# Extract unique lines from a file in order of their first occurence in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with a list of strings.  I'd like to extract out the unique strings, in the order that they first appear in the file.

So, for instance, if my file contains:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
baz
bar
foo
```

I'd like to output:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

If I just wanted the unique values, I could use `sort input|uniq`, but this sorts my result alphabetically.

Comment: Why not a simple script in perl, python, or any other language with dictionaries/hashes? It'd practically be a one-liner.

Comment: :-) So you want a pipeline-of-commands kind of solution?

Comment: At least with GNU sort, this would be `sort -u input`.

Comment: Looking at @Kevin's answer, I think it'll be hard for any scripting language to beat what he did in AWK.

Comment: "this would be `sort -u input`", except that it would sort the input, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @alexis Yes, that's what I'm looking for ideally.  However, a succinct one-liner would be sufficient in the event there isn't a great pipeline of commands solution.

Comment: @tinman, awk _is_ a scripting language, and this is exactly the kind of solution I meant (though I'd forgotten awk has hashes, so I was thinking more along the lines of choroba's perl equivalent.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what Nick was aiming at is something like this:

```
sort test.txt | uniq | xargs -I{} grep -Fnxm1 {} test.txt | sort -k1n -t: | cut -f2 -d:
```

Or maybe I'm reading too much into his suggestion. I think the `awk` answer is much cooler, though.

Comment: This is the sort of solution I was looking for, however, I agree, the awk answer is much cleaner:)

Answer (score 12):

Quite simple in awk:

```
awk '!a[$0]++'
```

Comment: +1. Nicely done. This is a good example why the command-line tools are sometimes the best/fastest path to a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Simple Perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++'
```

If your last line does not contain a newline, you might need to change it to

```
perl -nE 'chomp; say unless $seen{$_}++'
```

Answer (score 1):

bash 4:

```
declare -A seen
while read line; do 
  if (( ! seen["$line"]++ )); then 
    echo "$line"
  fi
done <file.txt
```

For bash <= 3, I would use something else that has associative arrays, like choroba's perl solution, or awk:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file.txt
```

Comment: shorter:`$ declare -A s;while read l;do ((! s["$l"]++)) && echo $l;done <file.txt`

Comment: Good point, @F.Hauri - no need to read the lines into memory.

Answer (score -1):

I can't quite get it, but something like this:

```
sort test.txt | uniq | xargs -0 -I {} grep {} test.txt
```

Maybe someone can fix?

Comment: sorting the lines changes the order.  If the file is cacbaba, OP wants "cba" to come out, not "abc".